# WCF service applying XSI namespace to soap envelope body element not to the content element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, wcf

We have a test WCF web service that returns an object:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyObject GetData();
}

//Deserialize MyObject instance from a string
public MyObject GetData()
{
    string sXml = TestApp.Properties.Resources.Template;

    object o = null;
    using (TextReader rdr = new StringReader(sXml))
    {
        o = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject)).Deserialize(rdr);
    }

    return (MyObject)o;
}
```

The xml representation for an instance of MyObject looks like:

```
<MyObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ...
    <notificationParty xsi:nil="true"></notificationParty>
    ...
</MyObject>
```

The actual response of the wcf service looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        ...
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <MyObject>
        ...
            <notificationParty xsi:nil="true"></notificationParty>
            ...
        </MyObject>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My question is, why does the .net framework move the xml:xsi namespace from the MyObject element to the Body envelope?

Comment: any solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

.NET isn't *moving* anything.

It puts the `xsi` namespace on the root element so it can be used in all children. Then, because it's in the root, it doesn't need to be added to the child.

It could have moved it to the `Envelope` element, or even put it on every element in this document, and it would still mean the same thing.

Comment: Some clients are trying to pull the MyObject xml fragment out and process it, which would be invalid in this case.  I am unable to alter the schema.  Is there any way, to make it easier on those clients to force my web service to define it in both places?

Comment: The clients are doing it wrong. From an XML point of view, the two case are identical. If they expect a literal `xsi` on the `MyObject`, then they are mistaken and should be fixed to process the data using an XML API and not using string manipulation.